# Birthday calculator in C? Having issue

Tags: c, calculator

This is my first program. I was trying to calculate my current age in `Year` `Month` `Day` format.

Here is the code i have written

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
int pd,pm,py,bd,bm,by,cd,cm,cy;`

        printf("Please enter current date\n\n");
        printf("Current Year\t :");
        scanf("%d",&py);

        printf("Current Month\t :");
        scanf("%d",&pm);

        printf("Current Day\t :");
        scanf("%d",&pd);

        printf("\nPlease enter your birth date\n\n");

        printf("Birth Year\t :");
        scanf("%d",&by);

        printf("Birth Month\t :");
        scanf("%d",&bm);

        printf("Birth Day\t :");
        scanf("%d",&bd);


        printf("\n\nYou Age Today\n\n");
        if(pd<bd)
        {
            cd=(pd+30-bd);

        }
            else(cd=pd-bd);
        if(pm<bm)
        {
            cm=(pm+12-bm+1);
        }
            else(cm=pm-bm);

        if(py<by)
        {

        }
            else(cy=py-by+1);

        printf("\t%d \t%d \t%d\n", cy,cm,cd);

    printf("Thank You For Using This Software");

    }
```

When i input the data in this it give me something like (1 day/month +-). May it be a problem of not considering leap year?

Comment: i dont think that code will compile, please provide a working example  of your code.

Comment: Not considering leap-years is definitely *a* problem.

Comment: Assuming there are 30 days in every month and not dealing with carries are also two fairly serious problems.

Comment: Rather than subtract 2 sets of Y,M,D, convert each set into a day number (like number of days since Year,1,Jan 1), then subtract.  Review `mktime()`

Comment: @Haris, This code do compile. It takes input and output aswell.

Comment: @chux, i don't know how to use this code `mktime()`. I haven't learn it yet. As i said it is my first code.